# Reading timestamp using DStream API in Spark Straming from Kafka

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I want to read the values from a Kafka topic with Spark streaming using Python. I am using the DStream API using the `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8` support (although deprecated). My code is the following:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

# Local SparkContext and StreamingContext (batch interval of 5 seconds)
sc = SparkContext(master="local[*]",
                  appName="Kafka-DStream-StdOut",
                  conf=SparkConf()
                  .set("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.5"))
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

# Input: DStream from Apache Kafka
stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(
    ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer", {"test-topic": 1})

# Output: show stream in the console
stream.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The problem is that I only receive the key and the value stored in Kafka, but not the timestamp. I see something like this in the console when sending random numbers each second from a Kafka producer (code [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/spark-examples/blob/master/kafka/kafka-rnd_int_producer.py)):

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-04-30 17:12:10
-------------------------------------------
(None, '69')
(None, '68')
(None, '6')
(None, '25')
(None, '73')
```

Is there any way to read the timestamp in Spark using this approach?

Comment: Is that timestamp from the data? It seems to me that Spark just prints the current timestamp instead of the timestamp the RDD was read.

Comment: DStream api is deprecated, as you say. Why not use SparkSQL?

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka message timestamp isn't part of the RDD record, like it is in [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10

[image]

Also, don't use Zookeeper to connect to Kafka. Always use the `bootstrap.servers` property